# App webview não funciona perfeito com YouTube

Tags: javascript, html, c++, webview

Crie um app webview do meu site, no PC ele funciona perfeitamente www.pipocaplayfm.com agora no webview ele não reproduz os vídeos como no site -  Link do app https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xCH5qpmt1vVHl1enhkSVJrYjQ/view?usp=drivesdk

Existe alguma solução que eu possa aplicar nele para funcionar corretamente ?

meu código :

' package com.creator.music;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
// set your custom url here
String url = " http://bemusic.vebto.com";
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

// if you want to show progress bar on splash screen
Boolean showProgressOnSplashScreen = true;

WebView mWebView;
ProgressBar prgs;
RelativeLayout splash, main_layout;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    prgs = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    main_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    // splash screen View

    if (!showProgressOnSplashScreen)
        ((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarSplash)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    splash = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash);
```

//      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
//
//          // get status bar height to push webview below that
//          int result = 0;
//          int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height",
//                  "dimen", "android");
//          if (resourceId > 0) {
//              result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
//          }
//
//          // set top padding to status bar
//          main_layout.setPadding(0, result, 0, 0);
//      }

```
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {

        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Recommended to use 3G/4G or Wifi ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // control javaScript and add html5 features
        mWebView.setFocusable(true);
        mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(
                this.getFilesDir().getPath() + this.getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/");

        // this force use chromeWebClient
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                if (prgs.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    prgs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                if (prgs.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    prgs.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // check if splash is still there, get it away!
                if (splash.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                slideToBottom(splash);

            }

        });

    }
    else{

        //Toast.makeText(this,"Your Device is not connected to Internet , Please Turn ON Data Services",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.setMessage("No Network Connection").setCancelable(false)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        Toast.makeText(this,"Your Device is not connected to Internet , Recommended to use 3G/4G or Wifi ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}




/**
 * To animate view slide out from top to bottom
 *
 *
 */
void slideToBottom(View view) {
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,
            view.getHeight());
    animate.setDuration(2000);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

/*@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}*/
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso esteja utilizando o Android Studio, faça o seguinte no seu arquivo java, na parte da criação do webview:

```
    Toast.makeText(this,"Recommended to use 3G/4G or Wifi ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // control javaScript and add html5 features
    mWebView.setFocusable(true);
    mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(
            this.getFilesDir().getPath() + this.getPackageName()
                    + "/databases/");

    // this force use chromeWebClient
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); //esta linha foi adicionada

    mWebView.loadUrl(url); //esta linha foi movida de lugar
```

Não esqueça de importar:

```
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
```

Comment: você se refere no MainActivity.java ? montei ele sim no Android Studio.
eu vou add aqui e ver se resolve.

Comment: Sim, me refiro ao MainActivity.java

Comment: eu vou adicionar o código na pergunta , não faço ideia onde adicionar ele.

Comment: Eu indiquei qual linha foi adicionada. Outra foi movida.

Comment: deixa eu entender por partes:

1 - Eu copie o código como vc passou 
2-  o código ficou assim na parte alterada :

' // this force use chromeWebClient
            mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {}); //esta linha foi adicionada

            mWebView.loadUrl(url); //esta linha foi movida de lugar

            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { '

Comment: Basta comparar o código que eu coloquei com o seu. Eu mexi em duas linhas apenas e comentei elas.

Comment: Eu percebi - Porém me aparece esse erro :  error: cannot find symbol class WebChromeClient.     ....  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Eu alterei o código da linha que foi adicionada. Tente novamente e não esqueça de importar o que for necessário.

Comment: essa parte vai abaixo também ?  
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;

Comment: Isso vai lá em cima, junto com os outros imports.

Comment: infelizmente nao funcionou

Comment: Não funcionou por causa de algum erro?

Comment: Não ... Deu TD certo, porém o vídeo não funciona como deveria.  Quando eu comprei esse app o cara disse que não era webview, pois eu sabia q webview não ia funcionar - já havia testado, mas ao comprar e modificar apenas a URL como ele pedi, nada funciona.  O mais invocado é que o app dele demonstrativo funciona com o site que ele usa como demo.

Comment: Daqui a pouco mais eu abro meu android studio aqui e acho a solução pra você. Comentarei aqui denovo após editar a resposta.

Comment: email ? jhonatamvitalino@hotmail.com

Comment: Eu descobri que se eu apertar o botão play duas vezes ele vai tocar o video, e agora ? como resolver essa ?

Comment: Então você terá que criar outra pergunta. Pois se o vídeo está funcionando, o código está correto. Pode ser alguma configuração no autoplay do html5.

Comment: Estou criando aqui já e vc puder dar um norte te agradeço

Comment: Coloque esta resposta como aceitável. Ajudarei você na outra pergunta.